# Does R support multi-level namespaces?

Tags: r, namespaces, multi-level

Is it possible to have a function in `R` under multiple levels of namespaces?

For example, can these functions exist?

```
Mymath::Trig::cosine( )
A::B::C::D::foo( )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, because the parser doesn't even handle this syntax: `a::b::c` gives

> Error: unexpected '::' in "a::b::"

i.e., we don't even get as far as searching for a thing in a namespace. In contrast `a::b` gives

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘a’